# Node.js sometimes doesn't respond to HTTP GET

Tags: node.js, firebug

I have a web page with the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/toolbar.css"/>
```

From time to time I see a problem that I can't properly reproduce. One of the resources sometimes never loads. Sometimes it is a JavaScript file, sometimes a CSS file like on the screenshot below. I have this default application setup:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
```

[image: CSS file is never loaded]

The logs look as if the CSS file has been loaded:

```
GET /javascripts/viewport.js - - ms - 11021
GET /stylesheets/toolbar.css - - ms - -
GET /javascripts/run.js 200 13.679 ms - 6035
```

A page reload "solves" the problem, but I want it to be stable!

I use this command to run Node.js:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" -v v0.10.26
```

I observe this within Firebug's *Net* panel. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you not use Current Version: v0.12.2 ?

Comment: I'll try another one, thanx for idea...

Comment: Does the CSS or JavaScript actually get loaded? I.e. do you see the CSS within the page and does the JavaScript actually get executed?

Comment: css is not loaded, js is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade from express 4.9.8 -> 4.12.3 seems to resolve the issue, at least i haven't observed the problem ever. No other changes were made.